# Change text of child

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a add to favorite system. I have a function which alerts the proper id I want to add.

I use:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function addfavo(state_name)
 {
    alert(state_name);
 } 
 </script>
```

And in my html I have a loop (with php) which shows all the images with the add to favorite links which looks like.

```
<div style="margin-top:40px;">
    <a onclick="addfavo('<?php echo $imgid ?>')"><b>Add to favourits</b></a>
</div>
```

So what happens is I have a lot of links to the same function with different parameters, but I only want the link that I click to change the text (to something like added to favorites)

Can some one help me in the right direction?

I have tried adding:

```
 $(this).innerHTML("test");
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use the `html` method:

```
$(this).html('test');
```

While `html` is a jQuery method, `innerHTML` is a property of a DOM element. If you were using pure JavaScript, you'd probably use:

```
this.innerHTML = 'test';
```

However, as you are using the `onclick` attribute on your HTML tag, `this` will not point to your current DOM element inside your function scope. In your case, I'd add a class to your elements, like `add_favorite` and add your text to another attribute:

```
<div style="margin-top:40px;">
    <a href="#" class="add-favorite" data-text="<?php echo $imgid ?>"><b>Add to favourits</b></a>
</div>
```

And then apply a jQuery event to it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.add-favorite').click(function(e) {
            var text = $(this).data('text'); // store the text in a variable
            $(this).html(text); // replace your element's html with your text
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MH6vY/

Comment: Thx works perfect!  i removed href="#" to not go to the top of the page.

Comment: In some browsers, if you remove the href attribute it loses the link style. I changed the JavaScript code so you can maintain the `href="#"` without moving to the top of the page when the user clicks.